# Javascript query selector

Tags: javascript

i have a question about javascript selector, i have 3 div elements with same class. 
and i wwat to change the color of second class.

```
    <div class="box">
        Element1
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        Element2
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        Element3
    </div>
```

i've tried following code :

```
var el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className;
el.style.color = "green";
```

but it doesn't works.

can you help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
var el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

adding `.className` to the end makes `el` into a string rather than an element.

Also you can omit `.body` from this is you like, its more usual to just say:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the .className JS ending.  Just use this:

```js
var el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
el.style.color = "green";
```

```html
<div class="box">
        Element1
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        Element2
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        Element3
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead to select the second DIV,

```
    var el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
    el.style.color = "green";
```